# reorder / rewrap bbcodes

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to reorder the BBCodes but I failed

so

[̶b̶]̶[̶i̶]̶[̶u̶]̶f̶o̶o̶[̶/̶b̶]̶[̶/̶u̶]̶[̶/̶i̶]̶ ̶-̶ ̶w̶r̶o̶n̶g̶ ̶o̶r̶d̶e̶r̶ ̶ ̶

I̶ ̶w̶a̶n̶t̶ ̶i̶t̶ ̶t̶o̶ ̶b̶e̶:̶ ̶

̶[̶b̶]̶[̶i̶]̶[̶u̶]̶f̶o̶o̶[̶/̶u̶]̶[̶/̶i̶]̶[̶/̶b̶]̶ ̶-̶ ̶r̶i̶g̶h̶t̶ ̶o̶r̶d̶e̶r̶

PIC: [image]

I tried with

```
<?php
$string = '[b][i][u]foo[/b][/u][/i]'; 
$search = array('/\[b](.+?)\[\/b]/is', '/\[i](.+?)\[\/i]/is', '/\[u](.+?)\[\/u]/is'); 
$replace = array('[b]$1[/b]', '[i]$1[/i]', '[u]$1[/u]'); 
echo preg_replace($search, $replace, $string); 
?>
```

**OUTPUT:**  [b][i][u]foo[/b][/u][/i]

any suggestions ? thanks!

Comment: And what should be the output of something like `[b]a[i]b[u]foo[/b]baa[/u]too[/i]`? There's no simple approach to achive a correct ordered output

Comment: @Philipp I want them ordered like in my example

Comment: @Philipp makes a valid point, for his input the output would not be deterministic. You should think about rules for it, your example does not suffice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

phew, spent awhile thinking of the logic to do this. (feel free to put it in a function)

**this only works for the scenario given. Like other users have commented it's impossible. You shouldn't be doing this. Or even on server side. I'd use a client side parser just to throw a syntax error.**

supports `[b]a[i]b[u]foo[/b]baa[/u]too[/i]`

and bbcode with custom values `[url=test][i][u]foo[/url][/u][/i]`

Will break with
`[b] bold [/b][u] underline[/u]`
And `[b] bold [u][/b] underline[/u]`

```
    //input string to be reorganized
    $string = '[url=test][i][u]foo[/url][/u][/i]';
    echo $string . "<br />";

    //search for all opentags (including ones with values
    $tagsearch = "/\[([A-Za-z]+)[A-Za-z=._%?&:\/-]*\]/";
    preg_match_all($tagsearch, $string, $tags);

    //search for all close tags to store them for later
    $closetagsearch = "/(\[\/([A-Za-z]+)\])/is";
    preg_match_all($closetagsearch, $string, $closetags);

    //flip the open tags for reverse parsing (index one is just letters)
    $tags[1] = array_reverse($tags[1]);
    //create temp var to store new ordered string
    $temp = "";
    //this is the last known position in the original string after a match
    $last = 0;
    //iterate through each char of the input string
    for ($i = 0, $len = strlen($string); $i < $len; $i++) {
        //if we run out of tags to replace/find stop looping
        if (empty($tags[1]) || empty($closetags[1]))
            continue;
        //this is the part of the string that has no matches
        $good = substr($string, $last, $i - $last);
        //next closing tag to search for
        $next = $closetags[1][0];
        //how many chars ahead to compare against
        $scope = substr($string, $i, strlen($next));
        //if we have a match
        if ($scope === "$next") {
            //add to the temp variable with a modified 
            //version of an open tag letter to become a close tag
            $temp .= $good . substr_replace("[" . $tags[1][0] . "]", "/", 1, 0);
            //remove the first key/value in both arrays
            array_shift($tags[1]);
            array_shift($closetags[1]);
            //update the last known unmatched char
            $last += strlen($good . $scope);
        }
    }

    echo $temp;
```

Please also note: it might be the users intention to nest the tags out of order :X

Comment: that's what i wanted, THANKS !